# Iframe with Javascript using Screen Resolution

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 web example.com (For Desktop) and example.net (For Mobile). I want to iframe it with detection of screen resolution size. I'm trying this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (screen.width <= 720) {
         document.write("<iframe src="http://example.com" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>");
    } else {
         document.write("<iframe src="http://example.net" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>");
    }
</script>
```

But the code is not working, Please help me with PHP or JavaScript code to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (screen.width <= 720) {
     document.write('<iframe src="http://example.com" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>');
    } else {
     document.write('<iframe src="http://example.net" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>');
    }
</script>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/c924s8ah/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You may try the code by replacing `"` with `'` for giving values to the attributes of `iframe` like `document.write("<iframe src='http://example.com' width='100%' height='100%' frameborder='0' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0'></iframe>");`